# How to loop through various columns in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to come up with a macro to drag down the columns. I just recorded a macro that drags down the columns. Is there a way I can put a loop which drags down all the columns that I have?

I came up with something this this but it does not work. This code stops working just after dragging down the first column.

```
Sub Macro3()
    '
    ' Macro3 Macro
    '
    For i = 1 To 100

        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4")
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4").Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

How can I make it work on all the 100 columns that I have? I appreciate any help as I am trying to learn this.

Comment: OK, so you want to 'drag down' column A through column CV (100 columns or however many you have populated in row 1). What determines how far you 'drag them down'? Is it always rows 1:4?

Comment: Yes it is usually a fixed number. Not always 4 though.

Answer (score 2):

Switch .AutoFill to .FillDown and do them all at once.

```
dim rws as long
rws = 4
with worksheets("sheet1")
    with .range(.cells(1, "A"), .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft))
        .resize(rws ,.columns.count).filldown
    end with
end with
```

Set rws to the total number of rows or figure out some other method of determining the total number of rows.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the help. Could you tell me where I was going wrong in my code and how to make it work. I was under the impression that I could record a macro for doing something and put a For loop. Am I going the wrong direction?

Comment: You performed the same .AutoFill operation on the same A1:A4 cells one hundred times. I consider using ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select 'bad practice' so I did not correct your code. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). No sense in correcting what IMHO is the wrong way to do things.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to do some reading now. How do I modify this code if I want to drag down every other column?

Comment: You would use a For Next loop with Step 2.

Comment: Thanks again. How would the code be modified if I want to do a vlookup first and then do the drag down?

Comment: You seem to think that this is a game of 20 questions; it is **not**. If you have achieved the goal of your original question but plan to make further modifications and are having difficulty then ask a new question using your own original code (not cut and pasted from my response above).